# How to protect garden against wildlife (roe, deer, boar)?

Tags: fruit-trees, grape-vine, protection, wildlife

I have a garden of 1500 m2 in Hungary, where I have some ~50 grapevines and ~20 fruit trees (apple, pear, cherry, prunes, etc.). I would like to protect these from the degradation of the local wildlife, mostly roe deer, red deer and boar. During winter, they eat the bark and the smaller branches of trees/saplings, and the fruits in summer/autumn, but they also destroy smaller ones by knocking out/trampling them.

The lot is not fenced and is not used all-year, only in spring/autumn weekends and through summertime. I am not allowed to deploy a regular fence (local regulation) and even if I could, deers would easily jump over it. An electric shepherd is allowed, though I'd avoid it if possible for many reasons (e.g. paying electricity throughout winter, needs destroying the nice hedge around that keeps eyes out, have small kids, etc.). Since I do not live there day-to-day or through winter, I cannot keep a dog there.

Is the only option to protect each tree/grapevine with by locally fencing them one/by one? What other options do I have? Would regularly sprinkling T-rex urine around the perimeter help? I can imagine there are motion-detecting cameras that play wolf howlongs -- but are they any good?

Comment: (I"m sure plenty of companies make Electric fences.  If you do want a Gallegher one they are made in my country - let me know and I can make some calls and help you find something which will work for you in winter - but if so, let me know where in Hungary you are so I can be more precise in my questions to them)

Answer (score 3):

If you can't fence the perimeter, fencing the individual plants would seem to be the only (reliable) option.

Solar powered (so no need for electricity from the grid supply) electric fence chargers are commonly available, though you can't go cheap on one you want to work through the winter when sunshine is low and short-duration. Not clear that you'd have to destroy the hedge - could be deployed inside the hedge or close to the trees/vines, and can be turned off when children are present, if desired. Portable (easily relocatable/removable) electric fencing is common.

Comment: Yeah - most electric fences use < 3 watts, many < 1 watt  (They use very high voltage, very low current - and a 1500 m2 area is tiny - although I expect you will want a bigger jolt for wild animals.)   You should be able to get one powered by a (deap cycle) battery which you occassionally swap out and/or supplement with solar power. [ I see you only get about 2 hours sunshine hours a day mid winter in Budapest - ouch!).  Maybe something likehttps://www.gallagher.eu/en_gb/20watt-solar-kit-bracket/495217 with a large  solar panel ?